# How to wait for keyevent until process to finish in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have using Qkeyevent to define key A and B event in QT. When i push A in the keyboard, will do process A() which will spend for 1 second. If i push B in the keyboard, it will do process B(). I want to update a global value by processing A() and get value in the process B(). However process A() spend for 1 second. If i push key B so quickly, i will get the wrong value.How to wait for for until process A() to finish when i push B so quickly in QT.

```
int g = 3;
A() {
  ...
  //cost 1 second
  g = 4;

}
B() {
  cout << g;
}
```

First, I push A. Then push B.If i push B in 1s afer pushing B, i will get g = 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your implementation details, but I would recommend to take a look at [this example](http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/qt-events).
Unless you do this in parallel (multithreaded), when event "A was pushed" arrives you invoke action `A()` in event handler `keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)`. In that case, event "B was pushed" should not be processed until `A()` is finished, because action A() will block event loop (for 1 second in your case). This way, when `B()` is called `A()` is already done.

Comment: Thanks you your comment.I just write keyPressEvent in the main thread.should i need to use thread?

Comment: @Moto Jack, this is the answer not a comment :) Ensuring that `A()` is finished when `B()` is called will give you the guarantee that `g` variable has already changed.

Comment: @hmm... I really hope you got it right. Good luck, anyway)